# "Play" is not defined - Pylance (reportUndefinedVariable)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm just starting to learn Python and am having trouble calling classes. I'm using Visual Studio Code. I've looked up the error but couldn't find anything helpful. All of my experience so far has been with Java and think I might be getting some stuff mixed up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
print("Lets play a game!")

dotheywantotplay = input("Do you want to play Rock-Paper-Scissors? (y or n) ")

if dotheywantotplay == "y":

    player1 = input('Enter first players name: ')
    player2 = input('Enter second players name: ')

    personchoice1 = input("What move will you do? [\"Rock\", \"Paper\", \"Scissors\"]")

    personchoice2 = input("What move will you do? [\"Rock\", \"Paper\", \"Scissors\"]")

    Play(personchoice1,personchoice2) // The error looks like its this line

else:
    print("I am so sad now :-(")
    exit()


class Play:
    def __init__(player1, player2):

        if player1 == player2:
                print("Tie!")
        elif player1 == "Rock":
            if player2 == "Paper":
                print("You lose!", player2, "covers", player1)
            else:
                print("You win!", player1, "smashes", player2)
        elif player1 == "Paper":
            if player2 == "Scissors":
                print("You lose!", player2, "cut", player1)
            else:
                print("You win!", player1, "covers", player2)
        elif player1 == "Scissors":
            if player2 == "Rock":
                print("You lose...", player2, "smashes", player1)
            else:
                print("You win!", player1, "cut", player2)
        else:
            print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")
```

*Above* was the original question for future reference. *Below* is the solution. Python is different than Java in that, one has to define classes before they are referenced. This means the classes must be at the top of your python file. Hope this helps some other Java nerd out there trying to write programs in Python...
[image: Program working]

```
    print("Lets play a game!")
    
    dotheywantotplay = input("Do you want to play Rock-Paper-Scissors? (y or n) ")
    




print("Lets play a game!")

dotheywantotplay = input("Do you want to play Rock-Paper-Scissors? (y or n) ")



class Play:
    def __init__(self, player1, player2, name1, name2 ):

        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.name1 = name1
        self.name2 = name2


        if player1 == player2:
                print("Tie!")
        elif player1 == "Rock":
            if player2 == "Paper":
                print("You Win ", name2,"!")
                print(player2, "covers", player1)
            else:
                print("You Win ", name1,"!")
                print(player1, "smashes", player2)
        elif player1 == "Paper":
            if player2 == "Scissors":
                print("You Win ", name2,"!")
                print(player2, "cut", player1)
            else:
                print("You Win ", name1,"!")
                print(player1, "covers", player2)
        elif player1 == "Scissors":
            if player2 == "Rock":
                print("You Win ", name2,"!")
                print(player2, "smashes", player1)
            else:
                print("You Win ", name1,"!")
                print(player1, "cut", player2)
        else:
            print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")


if dotheywantotplay == "y":

    player1 = input('Enter first players name: ')
    player2 = input('Enter second players name: ')

    personchoice1 = input("What move will you do? \"Rock\", \"Paper\", \"Scissors\"  ")
    personchoice2 = input("What move will you do? \"Rock\", \"Paper\", \"Scissors\"  ")

    Play(personchoice1,personchoice2, player1, player2)

else:
    print("I am sad now :-(")
    exit()
```

Comment: FYI, `// comment` is not the correct format for a comment in Python. Comments are defined like `# comment`.

Comment: `Play` needs to be defined above the place that it's used. Also you're missing the `self` parameter in `Play`'s init function. There's also no reason to be using the `Play` class; you could just make a function that takes two arguments, `player1` and `player2`, and works just fine without having a class at all.

Comment: @RandomDavis Poor Python. Bet it feels insulted I'm here commenting in java... Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is executed top to bottom, so all your Classes and finctions should be defined before called (so placed on top). Also

```
class Play:
    def __init__(player1, player2):
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
```

you should define your attributes inside your class like this before anything else, `self` it refers to the current instance of your class, everything in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Is the `self` sort of like java's `this` in constructors?

Comment: At the start of my class, I have to use `self.Variable`. So every where after using `self` in my python class "Play", I would have to put `self.player1` every time I reference that variable?

Comment: Also noticed that you have to put `self ` in the parameter list when defining your class...

Comment: I don't know Java but long story short a Class is like a blueprint and an instance of a Class is the actual object, so when accessing a class attribute the syntax is istance_name.attribute (and you get the value of that attribute relative to that specific instance). When writing a Class that instance_name is self.

Comment: LOL! Thanks. The other fixes for this issue is wild!